# Creating POS in ERPnext using API from postman

Tags: postman, erp, invoice, pos, erpnext

Here i want to create Sales invoice in ERPnext using API in Postman so please anybody can give the answer to this ?
I have Written the code which is giving the error u can go through it also
{
"naming_series":"PINV-.YY.-",
"supplier":"E Supplier",
"posting_date":"21-06-2022",
"due_date":"23-06-2022",
"currency":"INR",
"selling_price_list":"Standard Selling",
"items":
{
"item_name":"Dis",
"qty":1,
"rate":200,
"amount":200
},
"taxes_and_charges":"Input GST In-state - RL",

```
"taxes":[
    {
        "charge_type":"On Net Total",
        "account_head":"Input Tax SGST - RL"
    },
    {
        "charge_type":"On Net Total",
        "account_head":"Output Tax CGST - RL"
    }
],  
"base_grand_total":354,
"grand_total":354,
"payment_schedule_section":[{
    "payment_schedule":[
    {
        "payment_term":"Pay1",
        "due_date":"13-08-2022"
    }
]
}],
"accounting_details_section":[{
    "credit_to":"Creditors - RL"
}]
```

}

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What is the error message? Can you see anything in the Error Logs? Did you try Recorder tool?